# *ngFor Changing icon of a row in a table by its index

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I have a table with a list of songs, and
I want to be able to toggle the src of an icon

of a specific row by its index (play/pause, like/unlike).

As of now, the icon only changes in the first row no matter the row.

Working stackblitz- https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-zhvgft?file=src/app/play-list-page/play-list-page.component.html

**Component.html**

```js
<table *ngIf="playListSongs.tracks.length > 0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th>title</th>
                        <th>artist</th>
                        <th>album</th>
                        <th>release date</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <!-- | search:searchTerm -->

                    <tr *ngFor="let song of playListSongs?.tracks | search:searchTerm; let i = index;" [class.selected]="i==selectedRow">
                        <td>
                            <img src="../assets/play_line_icon.png" class="playBtn" (click)="togglePlaystateSong(song.track_id);getSongInfo(song);setClickedRow(i)" id="imgClickAndChange">
                        </td>
                        <!-- <img class="playBtn" src="..\assets\play_line_icon.png"> -->
                        <td><img src="..\assets\not_liked.png" id="likedImg" (click)="toggleLikedSongs(song.track_id);setClickedRow(i)" style="cursor:pointer"></td>
                        <td> {{song.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{song.artists_names}}</td>
                        <td>{{song.album_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{song.release_date | date: 'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>
                    </tr>


                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**Component.ts**

```js
//Row's index
setClickedRow(index: any) {
    this.selectedRow = index;
    console.log("this.selectedRow index:", this.selectedRow);
  }
  
 //Toggle liked/unlike 
  toggleLikedSongs(id:any){
    let likedImg = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("likedImg");
    this.playListsAPI.getLikeSongs().subscribe(data=>{
      this.likedSongsArray = data
    })
    for(let i=0;i<this.likedSongsArray.liked_tracks.length;i++){
      if(this.likedSongsArray.liked_tracks[i].track_id == id){
        this.playListsAPI.MarklikedSongs(id,false).subscribe((data:any)=>{
          this.likedSong = data
          console.log("removed:", id);
          likedImg.src = "../assets/not_liked.png"
        })
        break;

          
      }else{
        this.playListsAPI.MarklikedSongs(id,true).subscribe((data:any)=>{
          this.likedSong = data
          console.log(" added:",  id, this.selectedRow);
          likedImg.src = "../assets/liked.png"
          })
          break;
      }
    //  console.log(this.likedSongsArray.liked_tracks[i])
    }
    }
    
    //Toggle play/pause
    
      togglePlaystateSong(id: number) {

    let image = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange");
    let image2 = <HTMLInputElement>(
      document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange2"));
     
    if (!this.selectedSong || this.selectedSong.track_id !== id) {
      const token = this.playListsAPI.generateToken();
      const songUrl = `http://api.sprintt.co/spotify/play/${id}?access=${token}`;
      this.player.src = songUrl;
      this.player.load();
      this.player.play();
      // (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("bars")).value="0";
      // this.player.currentTime=0;
      
      
      image.src = "../assets/pause_line_icon.png";
      image2.src = "../assets/controller_icons/bar_pause.png";
    } else {
      if (this.player.paused) {
        this.player.play();
        image.src = "../assets/pause_line_icon.png";
        image2.src = "../assets/controller_icons/bar_pause.png";

      } else {
        this.player.pause();
        image.src = "../assets/play_line_icon.png";
        image2.src = "../assets/controller_icons/bar_play.png";
      }
    }
  }
```

Much appreciated!

Comment: Stackblitz is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You have equal IDs for each image: `imgClickAndChange`.

```
<img src="../assets/play_line_icon.png" class="playBtn" 
    (click)="togglePlaystateSong(song.track_id);
    getSongInfo(song);
    setClickedRow(i)" 
    id="imgClickAndChange">
```

Use `song.track_id` to make it unique and addressable.
.

```
<img src="../assets/play_line_icon.png" class="playBtn" 
    (click)="togglePlaystateSong(song.track_id);
    getSongInfo(song);
    setClickedRow(i)" 
    id="imgClickAndChange + {{song.track_id}}">


 togglePlaystateSong(id: number) {

     let image = <HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("imgClickAndChange" + id);

     // rest of the code
  }
```

The same goes for every other method. Always make IDs unique when you want to be able to properly address them.

Comment: Hi,
I keep getting a 'null' for "let image =....",   but the id is fine..

Comment: Can you please analyse the object in question (with browser developer tools), whether there id is correctly assembled.

Comment: Yeah, the id is correctly assembled.
I fixed the stackblitz link if you could edit it there(its pre your comment)

Comment: Will do, but I'll have to get back to you in approx. 8 hours.